# Python script not working as intended when called by task scheduler

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I have modified a python script that calculates the amount of words in a pdf file "Master.pdf" an writes the time and date plus the amount of words to a .txt file.

I have Python2.7 installed, I have installed Anaconda and I am using the PyCharm editor. When I open my PyCharm editor and run this script, no problems arise, the script executes and everything works.

As I would like this script to run every 15 minutes, I have made it a task using Task Scheduler. The task is "Start a program" the program is:

- C:\Users\alkare\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\python.exe - and the argument is - "C:/Users/alkare/Desktop/Report/WordCount.py" -.

whenever it runs I see the command prompt open, some text fly across my screen and then the command line terminal closes, BUT no changes are done to my .txt file.

here is the code I am using saved as "WordCount.py":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import os
import sys
import re
import datetime
import PyPDF2

def getPageCount(pdf_file):
    pdfFileObj = open(pdf_file, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    pages = pdfReader.numPages
    return pages


def extractData(pdf_file, page):
    pdfFileObj = open(pdf_file, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(page)
    data = pageObj.extractText()
    return data


def getWordCount(data):
    data = data.split()
    return len(data)


def main():
    pdfFile = 'Master.pdf'

    # get the word count in the pdf file
    totalWords = 0
    numPages = getPageCount(pdfFile)
    for i in range(numPages):
        text = extractData(pdfFile, i)
        totalWords += getWordCount(text)
        Now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    f = open("TrackingTimeData.txt", "a")
    f.write(Now[0:4] + "\t" + Now[4:6] + "/" + Now[6:8] + "\t" + Now[9:11] + ":" + Now[11:13] + "\t" + str(totalWords) + "\n")
    f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try to use a full path to TrackingTimeData.txt, maybe it is generated in another directory.

Comment: Didn't work. The two files are in the same folder. When I don't specify the full path I can make it run in my PyCharm editor. BUt I hadn't thought of that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then point the 'execution directory' for the scheduled task to the directory where you want to save the file.

Comment: That fixed it!
You are a GENIUS!! Thank you so much! I will name my first born after you!
This problem took me three days!

Comment: Hey guys.  The bug wasn't in your code, it was in a Windows task scheduler setup.  Technically this should probably be moved to ServerFault.com since it isn't code-related.

Also - @MauriceMeyer create an answer so Alexander can mark it accepted.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are allowing the program to fail without providing you any meaningful output (it sounds like it hits an exception and closes).

Instead of just calling main() without guarding it in a try block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

give yourself some slack here to gather information:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:    
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error {}".format(e))
        # drop into a command-prompt debugger:
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()

        # slightly more old-school, pause the window to read the exception:            
        import time
        time.sleep(15)

        # throwback to DOS windows
        import os
        os.system('pause')

        # read the error, come back to stackoverflow and describe the problem more, etc.
```

For example, mixing this with task scheduler, you'd want to right-click on your python.exe in Windows, go to properties, set "Run as Administrator" because maybe you're getting an access denied trying to read/write to a .PDF in some special directory.  This is just an example of the many guesses people could throw in to randomly help you solve an issue versus knowing exactly what the error is.

Comment: The same window would've popped up and disappeared.  You had relative and absolute pathing issues between code and task scheduler set-up (i.e. point the task sched execution to the working directory of the script).